# How to concatenate cell values until it finds a blank in Excel then return the result in the first row of the paragraph?

Tags: excel, vba, string, concatenation

I have a column with broken paragraphs split among different rows, and need to have the paragraphs concatenated into a single paragraph on the first row of the paragraph.

I want this:

```
Column1           | Column2
The weather is    | The weather is good today, how are you?
good today, how   |
are you?          |
                  |
I'm fine,         | I'm fine, thank you.
thank you.        |
                  |
                  |
                  |
There were        | There were 3 empty rows in Column 1 just before this paragraph. And should have 4 rows using after the macro.
3 empty rows in   |
Column1 just      |
before this       |
paragraph. And    |
should have 4     |
rows after        |
using the macro.  |
                  |
                  |
More text.        | More text.
```

I've tried multiple macros such as

https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/3574-excel-concatenate-until-blank.html
and
https://www.mrexcel.com/board/threads/concatenate-cells-in-a-column-until-blank-cell.607461/post-4531030

but they returned the result by not having it aligned to the original row. (The below is the first macro and they removed 1 blank row after each paragraph while totally disregarding consecutive blank rows).

```
Column1           | Column2
The weather is    | The weather is good today, how are you?
good today, how   | I'm fine, thank you.
are you?          |
                  |
I'm fine,         | There were 3 empty rows in Column 1 just before this paragraph. And should have 4 rows using after the macro.
thank you.        |
                  | More text.
                  |
                  |
There were        |
3 empty rows in   |
Column1 just      |
before this       |
paragraph. And    |
should have 4     |
rows after        |
using the macro.  |
                  |
                  |
More text.        |
```

Is there a way to concatenate strings until they hit a blank cell, then return the output on the cell of the first row of the broken paragraph?

Comment: What have you tried? Can you post an example of the code you are using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Paragraphing

- Adjust the values in the constants section.

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub Paragraphing()
    
    ' Define constants.
    Const sName As String = "Sheet1"
    Const sFirst As String = "A2"
    Const dName As String = "Sheet1"
    Const dFirst As String = "B2"
    Const dDelim As String = " "
    
    ' Create a reference to the workbook.
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook ' workbook containing this code
    
    ' Create a reference to the first cell of the Destination Column Range.
    Dim dCell As Range: Set dCell = wb.Worksheets(dName).Range(dFirst)
    
    ' Create a reference to the Source Column Range.
    
    Dim srg As Range
    Dim isNotEmpty As Boolean
    
    With wb.Worksheets(sName).Range(sFirst)
        ' Attempt to find the last non-empty cell.
        Dim lCell As Range
        Set lCell = .Resize(.Worksheet.Rows.Count - .Row + 1) _
            .Find("*", , xlFormulas, , , xlPrevious)
        ' Validate the last non-empty cell.
        If Not lCell Is Nothing Then
            Set srg = .Resize(lCell.Row - .Row + 1)
            isNotEmpty = True
        End If
    End With
    
    ' Write result to the Destination Column Range.
    
    Dim rCount As Long
    
    If isNotEmpty Then
        
        ' Write the values from the Source Column Range to the Source Array.
        rCount = srg.Rows.Count
        Dim sData As Variant
        If rCount = 1 Then
            ReDim sData(1 To 1, 1 To 1): sData(1, 1) = srg.Value
        Else
            sData = srg.Value
        End If
        
        ' Create Destination Array.
        Dim dData() As String: ReDim dData(1 To rCount, 1 To 1)
        
        ' Declare additional variables.
        Dim sString As String, dString As String
        Dim sr As Long, dr As Long
        Dim isNotWritten As Boolean
        
        ' Loop through each element (row) of Source Array...
        ' ... and write the result to Destination Array.
        For sr = 1 To rCount
            sString = CStr(sData(sr, 1)) ' Trim(...)  or Application.Trim(...)
            If Len(sString) > 0 Then
                If isNotWritten Then
                    dString = dString & dDelim & sString
                Else
                    dString = sString
                    dr = sr
                    isNotWritten = True
                End If
            Else
                If isNotWritten Then
                    dData(dr, 1) = dString
                    isNotWritten = False
                End If
            End If
        Next sr
        
        ' Write last Destination String (to the Destination Array).
        dData(dr, 1) = dString
        
        ' Write the values from the Destination Array
        ' to the Destination Column Range.
        dCell.Resize(rCount).Value = dData
    
    End If
    
    ' Clear the contents below the Destination Column Range
    ' ('whether there was data or not').
    With dCell
        .Resize(.Worksheet.Rows.Count - .Row - rCount + 1) _
            .Offset(rCount).ClearContents
    End With

End Sub
```

### EDIT:

- The following is a modified version for the `ActiveSheet` (one worksheet only) and includes an automatic `Trim` (not `Application.Trim`) which will remove the leading and trailing spaces but will leave possible remaining consecutive spaces intact.

```vb
Sub ParagraphingActiveSheet()
    
    ' Define constants.
    Const sFirst As String = "A2"
    Const dFirst As String = "B2"
    Const dDelim As String = " "
    
    ' Create a reference to the first cell of the Destination Column Range.
    Dim dCell As Range: Set dCell = ActiveSheet.Range(dFirst)
    
    ' Create a reference to the Source Column Range.
    
    Dim srg As Range
    Dim isNotEmpty As Boolean
    
    With ActiveSheet.Range(sFirst)
        ' Attempt to find the last non-empty cell.
        Dim lCell As Range
        Set lCell = .Resize(.Worksheet.Rows.Count - .Row + 1) _
            .Find("*", , xlFormulas, , , xlPrevious)
        ' Validate the last non-empty cell.
        If Not lCell Is Nothing Then
            Set srg = .Resize(lCell.Row - .Row + 1)
            isNotEmpty = True
        End If
    End With
    
    ' Write result to the Destination Column Range.
    
    Dim rCount As Long
    
    If isNotEmpty Then
        
        ' Write the values from the Source Column Range to the Source Array.
        rCount = srg.Rows.Count
        Dim sData As Variant
        If rCount = 1 Then
            ReDim sData(1 To 1, 1 To 1): sData(1, 1) = srg.Value
        Else
            sData = srg.Value
        End If
        
        ' Create Destination Array.
        Dim dData() As String: ReDim dData(1 To rCount, 1 To 1)
        
        ' Declare additional variables.
        Dim sString As String, dString As String
        Dim sr As Long, dr As Long
        Dim isNotWritten As Boolean
        
        ' Loop through each element (row) of Source Array...
        ' ... and write the result to Destination Array.
        For sr = 1 To rCount
            sString = Trim(CStr(sData(sr, 1)))
            If Len(sString) > 0 Then
                If isNotWritten Then
                    dString = dString & dDelim & sString
                Else
                    dString = sString
                    dr = sr
                    isNotWritten = True
                End If
            Else
                If isNotWritten Then
                    dData(dr, 1) = dString
                    isNotWritten = False
                End If
            End If
        Next sr
        
        ' Write last Destination String (to the Destination Array).
        dData(dr, 1) = dString
        
        ' Write the values from the Destination Array
        ' to the Destination Column Range.
        dCell.Resize(rCount).Value = dData
    
    End If
    
    ' Clear the contents below the Destination Column Range
    ' ('whether there was data or not').
    With dCell
        .Resize(.Worksheet.Rows.Count - .Row - rCount + 1) _
            .Offset(rCount).ClearContents
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Hi! Can you explain why I can't load this module from Personal.xlsb (got parsing error) but from an individual worksheet's module folder? What line do I need to modify to enable running this macro from Personal.xlsb? Also, I just noticed that I have some cells with multiple spaces that I wouldn't want to remove, so is it possible to solve this without using TRIM()?

Comment: 1. You will replace `ThisWorkbook` with `ActiveWorkbook` to make it work on the active workbook, the one you're looking at. If you don't know the worksheet name(s), you can replace the two `wb.Worksheets(...)` parts with `ActiveSheet` when this will be happening on one worksheet only. 2. It's kind of indicated how to trim e.g. use `sString = Application.Trim(CStr(sData(sr, 1)))`.

Comment: I've added another version to fit your needs.

Answer (score 2):

To output aligned with the paragraphs, keep track on where the paragraph starts.

Something like this

```vb
Sub Demo()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim dat As Variant
    Dim Result As Variant
    Dim rw As Long
    Dim rwOut As Long
    Dim InPara As Boolean
    Dim Sentance As String
    
    Set ws = ActiveSheet
    With ws
        Set rng = .Range(.Cells(.Rows.Count, 1), .Cells(2, 1))
        If rng.Row = 1 Then Exit Sub
        dat = rng.Value2
    End With
    ReDim Result(1 To UBound(dat, 1), 1 To 1)
    InPara = False
    For rw = 1 To UBound(dat, 1)
        If Not InPara And Trim$(dat(rw, 1)) <> vbNullString Then
            InPara = True
            rwOut = rw
        ElseIf InPara And Trim(dat(rw, 1)) = vbNullString Then
            InPara = False
            Result(rwOut, 1) = Sentance
            Sentance = vbNullString
        End If

        If InPara Then
            Sentance = Sentance & " " & Trim(dat(rw, 1))
        End If
    Next
    rng.Offset(, 1) = Result
End Sub
```

Comment: You forgot to remove the leading space e.g. `Result(rwOut, 1) = Right(Sentance, Len(Sentance) - 1)`. Any idea why it takes more than a second for this small amount of data? My lesson learned: `.Range(.Cells(2, 1), .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1)) = .Range(.Cells(.Rows.Count, 1), .Cells(2, 1))`.